# Django: Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='

Tags: django, django-urls

I am following this tutorial https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/extend_your_application/  but getting Templatesyntax error when trying to pass pk from html to url using path method.

With what i have read about this error this has something to do with braces and quotes but in this case i am not able to figure out the exact problem with the syntax.

This the listview.html

```
{% for vehicle_list_load in vehicle_list_loads %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{vehicle_list_load.vehicle_num}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle_list_load.Driver_name}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle_list_load.BusinessUnit}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle_list_load.CheckinTime}}</td>
            <td>{{vehicle_list_load.Type}}</td>
            <td>
              <a href= "{% url 'vehicle_movement:checkoutview' pk = vehicle_list_load.pk %}" class = "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden ="true" > Edit</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

this is vehicle_movements urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from vehicle_movement import views
app_name = 'vehicle_movement'
urlpatterns = [
path('checkoutview/<int:pk>/',views.checkout, name = 'checkoutview'),
]
```

this is main urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include(('vehicle_movement.urls','vehicle_movement'),namespace = 'vehicle_movement')),
]
```

This is the view

```
def listView(request):
    vehicle_list_loads = list(Checkin.objects.all().filter(Type ='Loading'))
    vehicle_list_unloads = list(Checkin.objects.all().filter(Type ='Unloading'))
    current_time = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    diff = current_time
    return render(request,'vehicle_movement/listView.html',
    {'vehicle_list_loads':vehicle_list_loads,'vehicle_list_unloads':vehicle_list_unloads,'diff':diff})
```

on clicking on edit this view needs to open

```
def checkout(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Checkin, pk= pk)
    return render(request,'vehicle_movement/checkout.html',{'post':post})
```

Comment: Remove the space between `pk = vehicle_list_load.pk` in ` "{% url 'vehicle_movement:checkoutview' pk = vehicle_list_load.pk %}"`. That should solve the issue.

Comment: @sam - yes it is solved.Can't believe i spent so much time for this thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your urls.py seems to be setup ok, I think the reason it is not working for you is because you have extra spaces around the parameter. The correct way, in the templates, to pass arguments is like this:

`{% url 'vehicle_movement:checkoutview' pk=vehicle_list_load.pk %}`